# Why can multiple <a>'s be :active?

Tags: html

Please have a look at the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33wRk/1

I know that this is not strict HTML, since I have a block `<div>` inside of an `<a>`.

As you can see, the `<div>` inside the `<a>` gets red if the `<a>` becomes the active link.

However, it stays red, even after another `<a>` gets active.

**How can multiple `<a>`'s be `:active` at the same time?**

**If the problem comes from the fact that I have invalid HTML, how can I change it to become correct?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a Chrome bug to me. I can't reproduce it in Firefox.

You can fix it by setting `a { display: block; }`

> since I have a block `<div>` inside of an `<a>`.

That's fine in HTML 5, the content model was changed to *transparent* instead of *inline*.